# Using SUBSTRING in JOIN condition

Tags: substring, abap, opensql, sap-erp

SAP says that the function SUBSTRING is not known when activating this code:

```
 SELECT a~client, a~loobj1, a~lotyp, a~proid, a~lockr, a~fdate, a~tdate, a~gpart, a~vkont, a~cond_loobj, 
        a~actkey, a~uname, a~adatum, a~azeit, a~protected, a~laufd, a~laufi
   FROM dfkklocks AS a
  INNER JOIN dfkkop AS b ON SUBSTRING( a~loobj1,1,12 ) = b~opbel
  WHERE b~augst = 9 AND a~lotyp  = '02'
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @gt_dfkklocks.
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING` is only supported as of ABAP 7.50. Be careful, you must use spaces after commas if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Thank you @SandraRossi ! What can I use? I tried LEFT but this also don't work...

Comment: The solution depends on the ABAP version you are using.

Comment: I think 740 (7.4)

Comment: BTW this SELECT is in a FORM. I dont know if that is important.

Comment: If you use S/4HANA, then you may do native SQL to use `SUBSTRING` directly at the database level. Otherwise, I'm afraid that the solution is a little bit complex, for instance doing a first SELECT on `DFKKLOCKS`, then use a SELECT FOR ALL ENTRIES on `DFKKOP`...